# JENKINS and JIRA integration, but fail to update JIRA issue after build

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

we are trying to update JIRA issue with Jenkins job's build result.

1. we install JIRA plugin on Jenkins, based on plugin wiki page, it supports updating JIRA issue with back pointers, and don't need any config change on JIRA side.

"Updating JIRA issues with back pointers
If you also want to use this feature, you need to supply a valid user id/password. If you need the comment only to be visible to a certain JIRA group, e.g. Software Development, enter the groupname.  Now you also need to configure jobs"

1. Jenkins global config  screen shot as below:
   [image]
2. In Job's config adding post build action as following:

[image]

3. Now gerrit trigger catch git commit msg with issue ID like following:

GERRIT_CHANGE_COMMIT_MESSAGE=SSOFEDU-3838   change #5 modified:   Jenkinsfile

but after jenkins job complete, jenkins does not update JIRA issue in commit msg.

anything we missed in setup? thanks for any hint.

Comment: do we still need add  Jenkins Add-on in JIRA server?